# How to track down source of memory leaks in luajit from calls to opencl api through FFI

Tags: windows, lua, opencl, luajit

A while ago I wrote fractal program in Lua. It works fine on my old Windows 7, and Windows 8 PCs.
I got a new laptop with Windows 10, and I run it with luajit 2.1.0 , that was working best for me in the past. Unfortunately some of the runs with various parameters failed with no errors or cause. And then I noticed that even successful execution is using too much memory. I tried my best to track down the problem using various builds of luajit from 2.0 to 2.1 , but only thing I can see is that memory leak is somehow connected to FFI calls to OpenCl api.
If someone is willing to take a look, I will provide complete code of program and required api dlls.
Attaching old demo lua code , that is also leaking on win10 , based on and using : https://github.com/malkia/luajit-opencl

cl-demo.lua : https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/files/4366334/cl-demo.txt

I'm sure that my post was not worded correctly, English is not my first language, and maybe not in the right place. I didn't mean someone waste time debugging my cobbled together old code, but to maybe point me in the right direction, or suggest some easily available memory errors inspection tool, like purify. I used to use it to find memory bugs, unfortunately its no longer available for single user.
Also I now have a strong suspicion that something is overwriting memory after calls to opencl. as a result calls to os.time, math.random & etc. result in code unexplained execution stop.
The following code after calls to OpenCL starts to behave weird, ii value in the last loop in the if statement all of sudden gets value like 0.13900852449513657 !

```
clfns[1]=true;
for ii=2,34,1 do clfns[ii]=false; end
for ii=2,34,1 do if string.find(formula, c2fns[ii] .. "[(]") then
 for jj=1,4,1 do if cdfns[ii][jj] then clfns[cdfns[ii][jj]]=true; end end
end end
for ii=1,34,1 do
 if clfns[ii] then
  cFuns = cFuns .. cfns[ii]; end end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a workaround for various problems my program had running on windows 10 and 8.1 with latest updates from Microsoft.
First to prevent luajit abrupt unexplained terminations running various versions of my lua code, I have rebuild luajit 2.1 under Microsoft Developer studio 2008 with alternative optimization options (/Ox /Ot). I was able to use similar compile options under 2015 & 2020 versions of MsDev , but had to add /guard:cf /D_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC , resulting in slower execution, up to 32%, and still some very weird sporadic aberrations.
To combat memory leak (over 100mb per fractal image generation) , I had to add collectgarbage() after every cl kernel program completion. And add release , free, and recreate memory buffer for every que of results from OpenCL code execution, which solves most of memory problems, but slows execution depending on size and complexity of running formulas from 19% to 41%.
added code :
clEnqueueReadBuffer(commands, output[jb], cl.CL_TRUE, 0, ressize, results, 0, nil, nil)
...
clReleaseMemObject(output[jbo]);
output[jbo] = nil;
output[jbo] = ffi.gc(clCreateBuffer(context, cl.CL_MEM_WRITE_HOST_PTR, ressize), ffi.C.free);

There still some memory issues when I run my program with OpenGL 3D output utilizing iup libraries, mostly due to garbage collection not catching up, but I can probably solve it by implementing use of 4 parallel threads using same content program space but separate kernels.

Still any suggestions, explanation or corrections would be greatly appreciated